# Regarding uniform and pointwise convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

If a real sequence $(f_n)$ of functions converges to a function $f$ uniformly over a domain $D$ except at a a finite amount of points $x_1,\cdots,x_k$, but it happens that at each of these points, $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$. Moreover, $f$ is continuous everywhere as well as the $f_n$'s.

Need it be that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on all $D$?

What about the case where the amount of points is not finite (but countable)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_n$ converges converges uniformly on each of finitely many sets, then it converges uniformly on the union of these sets. The proof is of the "let $N=\max (N_1, \dots, N_k)$" variety. So yes to your first question. (This doesn't really have much to do with continuity.)

No, on the second question: Let $D = [0,1/2] \cup \{2/3, 3/4, 4/5, \dots \}.$ Define $f_n(x) = x^n.$ Then $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1/2],$ and pointwise everywhere on $D,$ but not uniformly on $\{2/3, 3/4, 4/5, \dots \},$ hence not uniformly on $D.$

Comment: Your response to the first question only proves that the sequence converges uniformly on the union of these sets, but what about the excluded points? I am asking whether uniform convergence occurs on the whole $D$, taking into consideration the points at which uniform convergence doesn't but just pointwise convergence happens. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Note that if $a$ is fixed and $f_n(a)$ converges, then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\{a\}.$